# How do I isolate a level as its own variable in R?

Tags: r, names, levels

Within the dataset "PlantGrowth" there is only two variables, group and weight.

```
data("PlantGrowth")
names(PlantGrowth)
[1] "weight" "group"
```

The variable "group" 3 levels

```
levels(PlantGrowth$group) 
[1] "ctrl" "trt1" "trt2"
```

I want to be able to call the control and treatments of the variable "group" but I can't figure out how to separate them into their own variable.  I've renamed the levels to:

```
levels(PlantGrowth$group) <- c("control","treatment1","treatment2")
```

But now I want to be able to analyze control against treatment 1 and 2.  I've tried a bunch of different things like this:

```
control <- (PlantGrowth$group$control)


Error in PlantGrowth$group$control : 
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Obviously that is incorrect though  Thank you!

Comment: Show sample data and a desired output. Right now, what you typed up makes no sense. To provide sample data, put this into R and paste the output: dput(head(df,10)).

Comment: It is still unclear what you want. Analyze control how? By graphing them? By creating tables? Please show us what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want? (using `filter` from `dplyr`)

```
control <- PlantGrowth %>% filter(group == "control")
```

if you want you can also split your whole data frame by "group", like so:

```
split(PlantGrowth, PlantGrowth$group)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to run separate models for each group and compare results you can use following:

```
by(data = PlantGrowth, INDICES = PlantGrowth$group, FUN = summary)
```

or you can also build a matrix of regressors and use those:

```
model.matrix(~PlantGrowth$group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely most analysis functions would be able to use the group factor to split the data treatments, without you splitting up the dataset?

Not certain what comparison you'd like to make, but for example an ANOVA of your data:

```
ANOVA <- aov(weight ~ group, data=PlantGrowth)
```

Where the function uses your group variable to check for differences in weight.

Similarly when graphing, `PlantGrowth$group` could be applied to colour or shape appropriate points on the graph.